# Postman using DNS other than system-defined

Tags: dns, postman

For some reason my Postman presumably uses a local network nameserver (adverised via dhcp and proxied systemd-resolved) instead of the ones that are specified in /etc/resolv.conf and i'm looking to *resolve* that.

I have a number of problematic domains that points to addresses in my corporate VPN, and everything works fine except Postman. I can't disclose the domains in question, so i'll go with %host% to illustrate the examples.

I have a following setup on my machine:

- systemd-resolved on 127.0.0.53 that picks up ISP-defined DNS servers advertised by my routerthat i don't even know and proxies them
- dnsmasq listening on 127.0.0.1 using 127.0.0.53, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as backing servers (so that i get domains existing only on local machine in dnsmasq config, existing only in local network, such as ISP domain for my router, and all the global records then)
- /etc/resolv.conf by default points to 127.0.0.1
- My corporate VPN, when it is turned on, overwrites /etc/resolv.conf during operation with two 10.x.x.x servers
- /etc/nsswitch.conf (yes, it has to be brought in normal state) currently contains `hosts: mymachines dns mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files myhostname`
- both corporate DNS and global DNS contain %host% pointing to a couple of 10.x.x.x load balancers
- OS in question is Manjaro, Postman is installed using Flatpak/Flathub

Following scenarios further describe the situation:

- `getent hosts / ahosts %host%` correctly resolve address
- When i do `dig %host%` or `dig %host% 127.0.0.1`, regardless if my corporate VPN is turned on or off, i get correct addresses
- When i do `dig %host% 127.0.0.53`, then it's the only server i've tried that does not know about the %host% (this is the systemd-resolved that proxies dhcp-advertised servers)
- When i spin up nodejs and use the dns module, %host% is correctly resolved
- curl requests copied from Postman work fine without any modification
- However, Postman queries to %host% always fail with `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND %host%`
- At the same time, queries to hosts that are known to 127.0.0.53 are executed through Postman just fine
- Restfox, which is, as far as i know, a fork of Postman, works absolutely fine

What could be the reason and how can i change DNS server in Postman? I see that the error attributes to getaddrinfo, so a system call is responsible for not seeing the domain, yet i doubt that nothing of what i've tried is using the very same getaddrinfo.

Postman questions usually appear on SO and the problem most likely can be solved through Postman configuration, so i leave the question here, but feel free to move to another SE site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) dns is specifically off topic. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out to be Flatpak. The reason is that runtime is shipped with its own nsswitch.conf.

```
cat /var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/22.08/7fc5237fd8c82a24f1b7e09f8460a06e9e94f58815628b0439c16a1b618f3d29/files/etc/nsswitch.conf                                                                                                                       ✔ 
# Name Service Switch configuration file.
...
# resolve comes earlier than dns accompanied by action guard, thus the problem
hosts: files myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
...
```

Now, i'm not familiar with flatpak good enough, so i'm doing the stupid thing: just changing the file directly, and then everything starts working just fine